# Symfony command line does nothing

Tags: command-line, symfony1

I am having some problems executig the symfony command on my project root directory.

Some useful information:

1. symfony file permissions: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
2. symfony file content:

   ```
   chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
   include(sfCoreAutoload::getInstance()->getBaseDir().'/command/cli.php');
   ```

Every time I execute the symfony command, the result is empty. I'm currently using as development environment Ubuntu 10.04 as operating system and Eclipse PDT as IDE.

Can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the late answer but I had been submerged in work the past few days. After searching a lot, I finally found the problem.

Once I had installed the phpunit plugin, the auloading process was searching for libraries that are only installed with phpunit itself (it is signaled as requirement on the plugin page !). I found the problem when I finally remembered to inspect the php5 log file, that pointed me to the right direction.

Thanks all for the help!
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you execute it via php?

```
php symfony
```

Comment: Hi there!

Exactly nothing.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you type just

```
php
```

then enter in your shell?

It might be that you need to install the php5-cli package.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Then you should be able to execute

```
php symfony
```

or

```
./symfony
```